# Optimization data fetching

Tags: optimization, data-structures, hashmap, treemap

I have a TreeMap
`private final TreeMap<Integer,SXSSFRow> rows = new TreeMap<>();`

But I want to retrieve data from `rows` in constant time O(1)
so that you don't have to read behind (log *n*) at each iteration.
What can I do for this?
Maybe transfer data from TreeMap to another data structure, but will it be efficient?

Answer (score 1):

If you want lookup in constant time, even in worst case, you need something else than a `Map` data type.

With a `TreeMap`, lookup is O(log *n*) in all cases.

With a `HashMap`, lookup is O(1) in average, but can reach O(*n*) in worst case.

If you want O(1) lookup in all cases, you need an array, but the size of the array might get too big to be usable. And if you do something with the key, like a modulo or a hash to reduce the size of the array, congratulation, you just reinvented `HashMap` (with O(*n*) lookup in the worst case because of collisions).

Btw, transfering to another data structure will cost O(*n*) for an HashMap or an array, so it's not efficient if you read less than O(*n*) rows.

Comment: To be clear, O(1) average and O(*n*) in worst case means you get constant time lookup in practice (except with malicious data), but you shouldn't rely on that for mission critical operations.